# Proving that $ (A \triangle B) - C= (A - C) \triangle (B -C)$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-verification, proof-writing

Let A,B,C be subsets of a universe V.

I need to prove  $ (A \triangle B) - C= (A - C) \triangle (B -C)$

Here is my attempt. Could someone please verify it?

I used 2 auxiliary results for the proof:

**Lemma 1:**

> $((A-C) \cap B^c) \subset (A - C) \triangle (B -C)$

Proof:

$(A - C) \triangle (B -C) =\mathbf{[(A-C ) - (B-C)]}\cup[(B-C)-(A-C)]$

$\implies (A - C) \triangle (B -C) = \mathbf{[(A-C)\cap(B\cap C^c)^c]}\cup[(B-C)-(A-C)]$

$\implies (A - C) \triangle (B -C) = \mathbf{[(A-C)\cap(B^c\cup C)]}\cup[(B-C)-(A-C)]$

$\implies (A - C) \triangle (B -C) = \mathbf{[((A-C)\cap B^c)\cup((A-C)\cap C))]}\cup[(B-C)-(A-C)]$

$\square$

**Lemma 2:**

> $((B-C)\cap A^c) \subset (A - C) \triangle (B -C)$

Proof:

$(A - C) \triangle (B -C) =[(A-C ) - (B-C)]\cup\mathbf{[(B-C)-(A-C)]}$

$\implies (A - C) \triangle (B -C) =[(A-C ) - (B-C)]\cup\mathbf{[(B\cap C^c)\cap(A\cap C^c)^c]} $

$\implies (A - C) \triangle (B -C) =[(A-C ) - (B-C)]\cup\mathbf{[(B\cap C^c)\cap(A^c \cup C)]} $

$\implies (A - C) \triangle (B -C) =[(A-C ) - (B-C)]\cup\mathbf{[(B\cap C^c \cap A^c )\cup( B\cap C^c \cap C)]} $

$\implies (A - C) \triangle (B -C) =[(A-C ) - (B-C)]\cup\mathbf{[((B - C) \cap A^c )\cup( B\cap C^c \cap C)]} $

$\square$

**Proof of the equality:**

Let $x \in ((A \triangle B) - C)$

$x \in ((A \triangle B )- C) \iff [x \in (A \triangle B) ] \land [x\in C^c]$

$\iff [x \in (A - B) \lor x\in (B-A)] \land [x \in C^c] $

$\iff [x \in (A-B) \land x \in C^c] \lor [x \in (B-A) \land x \in C^c]$ ***(1)***

By ***(1)*** $x \in (A \triangle B - C)$ if and only if one of the following conditions hold:

***(i)***. $x \in (A-B) \land x \in C^c$

***(ii)***. $x \in (B-A) \land x \in C^c$

**Assuming (i):**

$x \in (A-B) \land x \in C^c \iff [x \in A \land x\in B^c] \land x \in C^c$

$\iff x \in A \land x\in C^c \land x \in B^c$

$\iff x \in (A-C) \land x \in B^c$

$\iff x \in ((A-C) \cap B^c)$

So, by Lemma 1 we have $x \in ((A - C) \triangle (B -C))$

**Assuming (ii):**

$x \in (B-A) \land x \in C^c \iff x \in B \land x \in A^c \land x \in C^c$

$\iff x \in B \land x \in C^c \land x \in A^c$

$\iff x \in (B-C) \land x \in A^c$

$\iff x \in ((B-C) \cap A^c)$

By Lemma 2, $x \in ((A - C) \triangle (B -C))$

$\blacksquare$

Is this correct? If it is not, what are my mistakes? And if it is, is there a simpler or clearer proof?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as i can tell your solution has no mistakes, however it can be done shorter. You can do set algebra and try to meet the equality by showing that one side can be written as the other side, my advice is to always work from the biggest side and reduce it to the smallest side, here is my proof

$$(A \triangle B) - C= (A - C) \triangle (B -C)$$
Start:
$$(A - C) \triangle (B -C)$$
Def Triangle operator
$$(A-C)-(B-C)\cup (B-C)-(A-C)$$
Def -operator
$$((A\cap C^c)\cap(B\cap C^c)^c)\cup ((B\cap C^c)\cap(A\cap C^c)^c)$$
DeMorgan
$$((A\cap C^c)\cap(B^c\cup C))\cup ((B\cap C^c)\cap(A^c\cup C))$$
Distribution and absorption one step
$$(A\cap (B^c\cup C)\cap C^c\cap B^c)\cup (B\cap (A^c\cup C)\cap A^c\cap C^c))$$
absorption
$$(A\cap C^c\cap B^c)\cup (B\cap A^c\cap C^c))$$
commutative property and def -
$$(A-B)-C\cup(B-A)-C$$
Def triangle/ distribution or/-
$$(A \triangle B) - C$$